# How do Free-RTOS and mbed OS handle ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, mbed, rtos

Do Free-RTOS and mbed OS poll for incoming data to be received (or use interrupts?)? If so, is there a risk that data to be received while the processor is handling another task (e.g. running a program) risks being missed?

Is received data then stored somewhere in memory, so it can be retrieved when a function such as receive(...) is called? I would imagine that receive(...) is simply returning data which the OS has placed in a particular memory location. Is this the case?

Comment: An RTOS is super fast and depends on flags being set/cleared as to whether it pays attention to a given port. In an RTOS all threads/ISR's must complete before the OS goes to something else. Of course priority flags can modify this. Any OS must support unusual conditions.

Comment: Ethernet cores have large (DMA) buffers where they store the incoming data. On top of that a protocol like TCP/IP can ask for re-transmission.

Answer (score 3):

To generalize your question a bit: how does a system handle data that must be read from the hadware and is only lateron read by the software? (The inverse problem also exists, for instance in an mpeg player: data is generated in blocks, and is consumed at a fixed rate). Sorted by 'response time':

- peripheral hardware often provides some buffering, ranging from the a-few-bytes buffer in a UART, to chains of data blocks in dedicated (multiported) RAM for Ethernet peripherals.
- DMA (direct memory access) can be used to put data directly in the CPU RAM, without intervention from the CPU.
- interrupts can be used to (temporary) get the CPU to handle an urgent task, like setting up a next data block for a Ethernet peripheral.
- when the action that must be performed in response to an interrupts is more involved, the interrupt routine itself sets a flag, which causes the RTOS to switch to a task that handles the event.
- when the response time is not very critical, the application can arrange that it polls the peripheral often enough to keep up with the data stream.
- in a master-slave protocol the master controls when the slave will send data, so it can arrange for this to happen when it (the master) is listening (polling) for it.
- when all else fails, the communication protocol can arrange for the data to be re-transmitted.